# How to print printer model on a PDF file

Tags: javascript, pdf

How to print printer model on a PDF file when I print the file?

Anyone know the correct Javascript to obtain this result?

Comment: If you're printing a PDF, what makes you think you can influence the printed result using Javascript?

Comment: Before print pdf, user have to select printer models from printer menu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this.  Once the user has a PDF open on your site, it's a bit out of your hands: they have the PDF, and when they go to print it, the dialog box to choose a printer is provided by the system--not by your site, and maybe not even by the browser, really.  I don't see how you can influence the content of the about-to-be-printed PDF between the time that the user chose to print it and the time that it actually is committed to paper.